# Dynamic rolling sum in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rolling-sum

How can I calculate the rolling sum of a column based on another column?

*Example:*

*Input data are the first 3 columns in the below table. The result column that I am trying to get is highlighted in green. I want to get the dynamic sum of 'Daily sales' based on the corresponding 'No of days' given.*

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the sum in the lower rows of your sample? Is there sample data missing?

Comment: @JvdV, yes the sample data are missing in the lower rows. Sorry about not mentioning that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula worked. Add the 'OFFSET' function inside the 'SUM' function to input the dynamic array.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is sample data missing, hence the lower rows will yield different results, here is yet another alternative:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=MAP(B1:B12,C1:C12,LAMBDA(x,y,SUM(x:INDEX(B:B,ROW(x)+y-1))))
```

Or just don't use `LAMBDA()` at all, but a simple `SUMIFS()`:

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B12,A1:A12,">="&A1:A12,A1:A12,"<="&A1:A12+C1:C12-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Microsoft-365 then could try the following formula for dynamic spill results.

```
=MAP(C2:C13,LAMBDA(x,SUM(OFFSET(x,0,-1,x))))
```

[image]